How do I add reverb on a recording?
Alright so I dont know much about Web Audio API and I was just ask to fix the Code. Right now I am able to record something and after that play it. It also has reverb on it. BUT my problem is that when I convolve ( I thinkt thats the word for it) my recording while a person is talking, the Audio in the Background starts sounding like a robot. If I dont add the reverb while recording everthing goes fine, but I cant figure ot how to add the reverb after the recroding is finsihed.
let recorder;

export function start(BRIR) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(async (dryStream) => {
                const audioChunks = [];

                const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

                // Create Nodes
                const microphoneNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(dryStream);
                const bg_Element = document.getElementById('audio_bg');
                const bg_stream = bg_Element.captureStream();
                const bg_sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(bg_stream);
                const wet_destNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
                const dry_destNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();

                let convolverNode;
                if (BRIR) {
                    convolverNode = audioCtx.createConvolver();
                    convolverNode.buffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(BRIR);
                }

                // Connect graph
                // For wet audio (convolved with BRIR)
                if (convolverNode) {
                    microphoneNode.connect(convolverNode).connect(wet_destNode);
                } else {
                    microphoneNode.connect(wet_destNode);
                }

                // For dry audio (without convolution)
                microphoneNode.connect(dry_destNode);

                // Connect background audio directly to output
                bg_sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

                // Media Recorder for wet audio
                const wetStream = wet_destNode.stream;
                recorder = new MediaRecorder(wetStream);
                recorder.start();

                recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
                    audioChunks.push(e.data);
                };

                recorder.onstop = (e) => {
                    console.log('Stop recording');
                    audioCtx.close();
                    const wetBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/mp3; codecs=opus' });

                    resolve({ wetBlob });
                };
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error);
                reject(error);
            });
        } else {
            reject(new Error('navigator.mediaDevices not supported'));
        }
    });
}

export function stop() {
    if (recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
    }
}

Thats the best Code I have been given so far and used ChatGpt to fix it but doesnt work.
So I really just want to record my voice while there is an audio playing and after that I want to convolve the recorded audio with my BRIR so it has reverb.
